# How/what does the rails bin/rails file do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Now, I've used Rails enough to know what the rails command *does*, but *how* it does it interests me.

The bin/rails file (from github) is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

begin
  require "rails/cli"
rescue LoadError
  railties_path = File.expand_path('../../railties/lib', __FILE__)
  $:.unshift(railties_path)
  require "rails/cli"
end
```

As far as I know (and please correct me if I'm wrong), require doesn't run code, just loads classes etc.

I could also not find the rails directory in the root of them gem, so I'm a little confused where that's hiding as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`require` does run code. This will include any code outside of any classes and modules in the file being required plus any executable code in classes and modules that is outside of method declarations. As [neutrino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125805/neutrino) has said, the ruby interpreter is running the code in the file being required in order to define the classes in the source. However this might be a bit clearer if you try it out with something that has an obvious side effect like a `puts` statement.

Try this as a simple example. Create a file `hello.rb` containing `puts "Hello World"` then go into irb:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'hello'
Hello World
=> true
```

Next, try this example of a simple class with some executable code in its body. Create a file `hello2.rb` containing:

```
class Hello
  puts "class Hello being defined"
end
```

then require this from irb:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'hello2'
class Hello being defined
=> true
```

Going back to `bin/rails`, take a look at the [source for rails/cli](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/cli.rb) in Github to follow the chain of how it works.

Answer (score 4):

All ruby code is executable code. Class/module/method definitions are also executed by the interpreter, so when you say that `require` loads classes, it's true because loading a class means executing its code :)

Here is the file you are looking for: [cli.rb](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/cli.rb). It's in railties.